# Comparing content and quantity between lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check for the quantity of a string in a list, by making a for loop with another list. I'm searching for the index of doubles in list1, but my problem is as soon as the first string is found in the list the index does not go up when the second instance is found. I expect in this case 0,1,2,3 but in reality it's 0,1,1,3.

```
list1 = ['ABBA', 'CBBA', 'CBBA','DBBA']
list2 = ['ABBA','CBBA','DBBA']

for line in list1:
    for marker in list2:
        if marker in line:
            print("Marker found", list1.index(line))
```

Comment: `list1.index` always gives you the *first* index, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations).

Comment: Ok I understand your feedback in non loop cases. But as the for loop is going through the list I expected the index would advance as well.

Comment: @MatthiasTT how long would you expect it to advance for. What would you expect to happen when it reached the end? How could you reset it if you wanted to search again? (obviously all these questions are wrong, but it's useful to imagine so you can realise how badly you're conceiving of things)

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) the list so you know which line is at which index:

```
lines = ['ABBA', 'CBBA', 'CBBA','DBBA']
markers = ['ABBA','CBBA','DBBA']

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    for marker in markers:
        if marker in line:
            print("Marker found", index)
```

Output:

```
Marker found 0
Marker found 1
Marker found 2
Marker found 3
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think of this. Numbering is indeed a good way to make them more traceable.